# How I can show only certain cells taken from Dictionary in a tableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am using a dictionary in order to fill a tableview.
Trying to appear only cells that have a certain userID, but it return also the cells that doesn't have this userID.
I have managed to count only the items from dictionary with the certain userID and if for example my dictionary has 8 entries and I need to show only the last 2 entries which have different userID, it returns 2 empty cells (which are the first 2 in the dictionary.

How I can get only the cells with the certain userID?

```
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    var returnCount:Int = 0
    let currentUserId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")

    for place in places {
        if place["userID"] == currentUserId {
            returnCount++
        }
    }

    return returnCount

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let currentUserId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")

    let currentPlacesUserId = places[indexPath.row]["userID"]

        if  currentPlacesUserId == currentUserId {

            cell.textLabel!.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["issue"]

        }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that you should not do this kind of logic inside de tableView delegate methods. Try getting the places from that userId when you load this array.

If you really want to proceed with the approach you are currently using try the following:

Not sure if this gonna work, but you are creating the cell even if it doesnt have the user Id you want. Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let currentUserId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")

    let currentPlacesUserId = places[indexPath.row]["userID"]

        if  currentPlacesUserId == currentUserId {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

            cell.textLabel!.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["issue"]

            return cell
        } else{
             return nil
        }
}
```

Comment: cannot return nil on a tableview. But I need something similar to this.

Comment: Where are you loading this data? You should remove the data u dont want to display from the places on the viewDidLoad() or passing the data to another dictionary. Than u will not need to do this logic on the tableView. Unfortunately this is the only way

Comment: I was hoping to avoid transferring data between dictionaries, but this is how I will do it.